# ping IP addresses constantly

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ip-address

I am a project engineer and I am working on a multiplexer system and I am now writing the software to control the system using visual basic 2010 as the company won't spend the money for a profession software developer.  The main program is working very well but I have a quick question for people that are much more experienced.  I have 10 x Ethernet devices within my system (topside and subsea) that I need to monitor the connection status of.

The way I am going about this is pinging each IP address in sequence over and over in a loop and if it is connected/disconnected I change a pitcurebox from an imagelist control to show the connection status.  This is done in a new thread to stop the main interface from becoming unresponsive and it all works but is slow to update of course, so...

My question to you guys is there a better way of showing connected/disconnected IP addresses on the system?  I have searched the internet but everything I find isn't quite what I'm looking for, or I'm just sh*te at searching.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: This is very hard to answer without more definitions from your side, what is an connected IP-address? Is it an IP from which you get an response to an ICMP-ping packet? Have you had a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping(v=vs.110).aspx ? And what do you mean with "a better way", do you mean a new program? Or change to your current program?

Comment: In your infinite loop I would also implement a Thread.Sleep(2000); (2 seconds timeout between every iteration this will considerably drop the usage of resources in your program. Also how are you currently testing whether a device is online/offline?

Comment: Sorry, A connected IP address is indeed an IP I can get a response from within the system,  I have a topside system with all modules running 10.0.0.XXX IP's and the HV modem passes the data to the subsea modem and all subsea addresses with 10.0.100.XXX IP's.  I have looked at the ping class but was wondering if there is more efficient way of determining if an IP address can if reached rather than just pinging one after the other, seems a bit ham fisted way of doing things.  Sorry I'm a fairly new programmer.

Comment: I do indeed use the sleep.thread currently set at 5000ms. I use an If - then - else statement. If the pinged IP returns set to 'on' else its unreachable and set image to 'off'.  Its fine but the system is slow to respond when I purposely disconnect a device to test.  Are there any objects or classes to monitor specifc IP/ports (they will not change) and fire an event when a change is detected or am I making is too complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using an UI-application, have a look at the `Ping`-class as well as the [async method for pinging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193994%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), depending on your normal ping times and how heavy the network traffic is I would change the ping time, but at least once a second is needed.

In the form use a timer which calls some method, ex `async void UpdateMachineStatus(IPAdress adr)` which awaits the call to the pinger, ie `var result = await Ping.SendPingAsync(adr)`, and then does something. This would use a non-blocking wait and would not cream system resources.

Harness the power of async!

Comment: Ok been playing around with this all afternoon.  It works perfectly.  I did what you said flindeberg (thank you soo much), created a timer which calls a subroutine that loops through an array containing my IP addresses and sends an asnyc ping to each.  Then I created a ping complete event handler that deals with the ping and if IPstatus = success if keeps/changes the status image to green else keeps/changes the status image to 'off'. My program is now very responsive and the 'status' changes MUCH quicker now when I unplug a network plug to test.

Comment: @NorthernJoy, glad I could be of help, and thanks a lot for getting back and saying so :)